# Adding shortened or hyperlinks to word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am writting some document with links to external websites, but some links are to large to simply be tossed in to the word file and i was thinking if there's a way to attach the hyperlink to any word/phrase in the document for example:

> [www.google.com/verylonglinkhereforexample](http://www.google.com/verylonglinkhereforexample)

As if i would do in for a hyperlink tag:

check the `site` here, where clicking site, would take me to the desired link behind site word. Or is there any alternative at all to reduce links instead of tossing large links to the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an easy one.

Assuming you're using Office 2016/2019 (I'm not 100% sure about the others, but I'm sure it would be pretty similar), the easiest way to do this is:

First, highlight the text you want to go to the hyperlink.

1. Go to the insert tab
2. Press 'Link'
3. At the top of the dialog box, check that the text to display is the text you highlighted
4. At the bottom of the dialog box, enter the actual hyperlink
5. Press OK
6. Enjoy!

Comment: Awesome!, gotta wait 10 mins to accept your answer, ill keep an eye, but thank you very much

Comment: No problem! I updated the answer so you can just highlight some text already in the doc, then follow the rest of the steps.